# Anotação @ManyToMany na mesma entidade/tabela

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Minha Classe:

```
@Entity
public class Report extends  AbstractModel implements IReport {

@Column
private String nome;

@Column
private byte[] arquivoJrxml;


@ManyToMany
private List<Report> subReports;
```

Minha duvida:

Minha classe Report, possui vários SubReports, ou seja, muitos para muitos, pois vários SubReports estão em vários relatórios, minha duvida fica por conta da anotação, levando em consideração que um Subreport é um objeto do tipo report, minha anotação precisa de mais atributos, estou correto usando usando SubReport e Report na mesma Classe/Tabela?

Comment: Não vi no seu código isto: _"levando em consideração que um Subreport é um objeto do tipo report"_, só vi a entidade `Report`. Existe uma entidade `SubReport`? Vendo apenas o código mostrado, parece que está correto sim, mas eu não usaria @ManyToMany pois gosto de mapear a tabela intermediária, se não fica muito "mágico" e menos flexível.

Comment: De fato Dherik, obrigado pelas considerações

Comment: Respondendo, sua pergunta, não exite entidade SubReport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...estou correto usando usando SubReport e Report na mesma Classe/Tabela?

A resposta para essa pergunta depende das suas regras de negócios, você precisa analisar todo o contexto, e definir se você precisa de uma classe SubReport ou não. Por exemplo, se as duas classes tiveram os mesmos atributos e são usadas no mesmo contexto, é um sinal que você só precisa de uma classe. Mas se todo SubReport tiver dados(atributos) que não estão presentes no Report, pode ser um sinal que SubReport é uma subclasse ou que ela contenha a classe Report.

> ...levando em consideração que um Subreport é um objeto do tipo report, minha anotação precisa de mais atributos?

A anotação Many to Many possui alguns atributos que são sempre necessários(jointable, joinColums, ...), mas o grande segredo neste cado é que você vai precisar de duas coleções na mesma classe, uma que represente os SubReports de um Report, e uma que representa os Reports de um SubReport, afinal quando são duas classes diferentes, cada uma delas possui uma coleção que representa o relacionamento Many to Many. Ex.:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="report_subreport",
 joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_subreport"),
 inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_report")
)
private List<Report> subReports;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="report_subreport",
 joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_report"),
 inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_subreport")
)
private List<Report> reports;
```

Neste exemplo de código considerei que a tabela união se chama report_subreport, e que esta tabela tem duas colunas: id_report e id_subreport, que na verdade são uma referência para chave primária da tabela report, como se fosse uma tabela união de duas tabelas diferentes, mas neste caso é a união de uma tabela que se relaciona consigo mesma, tanto id_report e id_subreport apontam para a tabela report, mas para registros diferentes desta tabela, onde um deles é o report e outro é o subreport.

Comment: Obrigado Resende, entendi !